# Ajax effects and validation using ajax in cakephp not working

Tags: cakephp-2.0

i have put these files in my

index.ctp file for validations and

ajax effects.

Html->script('jquery',FALSE); 

?>
Html->script('validation',FAL

SE); ?> //i have created it
Html->script('prototype',FALS

E); ?>
Html->script('scriptaculous',

FALSE); ?>

if I run code before including file

prototype.js and scriptaculos.js it

was working fine. and when included

other files ajax validation stop

working but effects are working.

my effect code is like,

- Click here for a 

  demo!
- Reset

so, what could be the solution?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems when working with prototype and jquery at the same time, the ideal is to work with only one.

But you can fix it with this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/